# Foreign key against same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I just did an DDL export from a existing schema and i found this:

```
ALTER TABLE SMB ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SMB_ID FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES SMB (ID);
```

This is usefull for something?
Could it be a design problem?

Thanks

Comment: Either the tables or the columns should have been different. Primary key ensures uniqueness, but foreign key doesn't. So, your use case is useless.

Answer (score 1):

If they were different columns then I could've presumed that this is about hierarchy. But in this case for me it seems useless.

Comment: Or even different tables, ideally speaking.